# c++ -- Confusion about using Default Argument

Tags: c++

For example, there're 3 files, `sum.h`, `sum.cpp`, and `main.cpp`.

`sum.h` --

```
    ...
    int sum (int, int, int);
    ...
```

`sum.cpp`

```
    ...
    int sum (int a, int b, int c=10) { 
       return a + b + c;
    }
```

`main.cpp`

```
   ...
   cout << sum (1, 2) << endl;
   ...
```

The compiler throws an error saying `too few arguments to function...`.

It works fine if I code as `cout << sum (1,2,3) << endl;`
But how to just pass only 2 argument?

Comment: Put the default argument in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default function arguments must go in the function declaration that the call site sees.

```
int sum (int, int, int = 10);
```

They are required at the expression where the function is called. The implementation shouldn't care if it is passed the default or not.

Furthermore, you can re-declare the function in a smaller scope, and give completely different default arguments. This code snippet is taken from the c++17 standard draft and demonstrates what I mean:

```
void f(int, int);
void f(int, int = 7);
void h() {
  f(3);                         // OK, calls f(3, 7)
  void f(int = 1, int);         // error: does not use default
                                // from surrounding scope
}
void m() {
  void f(int, int);             // has no defaults
  f(4);                         // error: wrong number of arguments
  void f(int, int = 5);         // OK
  f(4);                         // OK, calls f(4, 5);
  void f(int, int = 5);         // error: cannot redefine, even to
                                // same value
}
void n() {
  f(6);                         // OK, calls f(6, 7)
}
```

Theoretically (don't do this in practice), you can even have different headers that declare the same function with a *different* default parameter value. And it will work as expected, so long as they aren't both included in the same translation unit.

Comment: @Remy, I'd appreciate if you suggest the edit in the future. I just lost a paragraph I was editing in.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the default value in the prototype (the function definition in the .h file):

```
int sum (int, int, int=10);
```

No need to specify it in the function implementation.